# Exclude one cell row from swipe to delete

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I currently have set up a UITableView which is populated with several cells. I'd like to disable the swipe to delete function for only one cell, but keep it for all the others.

So far, I've tried the following with no luck:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let presets = defaults.objectForKey("presets")!

    if indexPath.row == (presets.count) {
        // I want this cell non-removable
        UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
    }

    else {
        let presets = defaults.objectForKey("presets")?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
        presets.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        defaults.setValue(presets, forKey: "presets")
        defaults.synchronize()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }

}
```

Really clueless on what to do here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` method, like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath.row != (presets.count)
}
```

The `indexPath.row != (presets.count)` expression returns `true` for all rows except `presets.count`, disabling all editing functionality on it.